# Declaring ViewModel using Constructor Injection in XAML

Tags: xaml, prism, unity-container, constructor-injection

I'm trying out Unity and I'm having problems declaring my viewmodel in XAML. Can you help me out?
XAML:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <search:SearchBoxViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Constructor:

```
   [ImportingConstructor]
    public SearchBoxViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }
```

When I try to execute I get a resolutionfailedexception.
This worked when the viewmodel had an empty constructor. It seems as if it's having problems with the constructor injection.

If I load the module like this:

```
var searchView = Container.Resolve<SearchBoxView>();
        searchView.DataContext = Container.Resolve<SearchBoxViewModel>();
        //RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.SearchRegion, typeof(SearchBoxView));
        RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.SearchRegion].Add(searchView);
```

It works.

Is there any possibility to do this with xaml ( with I personally think is better )?

By the way: I'm creating an application with wpf that primarily communicates with a webservice. What should I rather user: unity or MEF and what are the big differences between the two?

Thanks,
Raphi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379.aspx:

> **Requirements for a Custom Class as a XAML Element**
>
> In order to be able to be instantiated as an object element, your
>   class must meet the following requirements:
>
> - Your custom class must be public and **support a default
>     (parameterless)
>     public constructor**. (See following section for notes regarding
>     structures.)
> - ...

So, if you want to use dependencies, you should right something like:

```
var searchView = Container.Resolve<SearchBoxView>();

public class SearchBoxView: UserControl
{
  [Dependency]
  public SearchBoxViewModel ViewModel
  {
    get { return (SearchBoxViewModel)DataContext; }
    set { DataContext = value; }
}
```

Comment: Yea i knew that it wouldn't work normally. thought that maybe the prism devs had some handy hack that maybe would've implemented this. too bad. but your solution is still better than mine. Thanks!

Comment: @raphi011 Actually, if I remember correctly, it's not mine solution, I had stealed it from Prism book :)